# Function Results Not Rendering On React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create an app that lets me grab fetched data from a function and then outputting the results on a different file. I am getting two errors when I try to run this, and they limit me from posting the resuts in a table. The first error is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')`, while the second error is that it does not allow text children in a table? I am confused as to how to make this output. The file `ShowStock.js` grabs data from `Stock.js`, which uses export functions from a different file. Fetching the data works and I can get all the data to print to the console, it is just rendering it on the page that is an issue.

**ShowStock.js**

```
const ShowStock = () => {
    const { user } = UserAuth();
   
    const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]);
    const dir = "users/" + user.uid + "/invList"
    const q = collection(db, dir);
    const [docs, loading, error] = useCollectionData(q)

    return (
        <div>
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Stock Ticker</th>
                        <th scope="col">Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Dividend Yeild %</th>
                        <th scope="col">Dividend Amount Annually</th>
                        <th scope="col">Annual Dividend Profits</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {loading && "Loading..."}
                {!loading && 
                <tbody> 
                    {docs?.map((stock) => {
                        let price = 0;
                        let divA =
                        let total = 0;
                        const x = new Stock({stockTicker: stock.stockTicker, shares: 1});
                        
                        console.log(x.then(function(res) {
                            price=res['price'];
                            divA = res['divYield']
                            total = res['annual']
                            console.log(price + " " + divA + " " + total);
                        }));
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                {stock.stockTicker}
                            </th>
                            <td>{price}</td>
                            <td>{divA}</td>
                            <td>{total}</td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    })}
                </tbody>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
  )
}

export default ShowStock
```

**Stock.js**

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import { FetchStockPrice, FetchStockDividend } from './StockData';

function Stock ({stockTicker, shares}) {

    let data = {};  


    const dataObject = async() => {
        let price = await FetchStockPrice(stockTicker);
        let div = await FetchStockDividend(stockTicker);
        let divAmnt = (div * price).toFixed(2);
        let annual = divAmnt * shares;
        data = {
            price: price.toFixed(2),
            divYield: div,
            annual: annual
        }
        console.log(data);
        return data
        
    }
    return dataObject();
}

export default Stock;
```

I am expecting a table that lists out the Stock Ticker, Price, Dividend, and Annual Return. I tried mapping it through in a seperate function, but that did not work.

Comment: Please provide a runnable sandbox :)

Comment: You need to separate JS code from the returned JSX

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of little problems here, but at the core you want to use a list of promise results in a React component.

You can listen for new docs and save their Stock results on the component state.

```
async function Stock({ stockTicker, shares }) {
  const price = await FetchStockPrice(stockTicker);
  const div = await FetchStockDividend(stockTicker);
  const divAmnt = +(div * price).toFixed(2);
  const annual = divAmnt * shares;
  return {
    price: price.toFixed(2),
    divYield: div,
    annual,
  };
}

const App = () => {
  const [docs] = useCollectionData();

  const [decoratedStocks, setDecoratedStocks] = useState<Array<Awaited<ReturnType<typeof Stock>>>>([]);

  const decorate = async () => {
    const ps = docs.map(d => Stock({ stockTicker: d.stockTicker, shares: 1 }));
    const results = Promise.all(ps);
    // Probably want to attach each result back on to its
    // doc, but w/e you can do anything at this point
    setDecoratedStocks(results);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    // Every time docs updates, get and set new decorations
    // Lots of room for optimizations here depending on the behavior of docs
    decorate();
  }, [docs]);

  return your jsx
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am looking at the code and the line `const [decoratedStocks, setDecoratedStocks] = useState<Array<Awaited<ReturnType<typeof Stock>>>>([]);` returns an error saying expression expected. Do you know why that is.

Comment: If you are not using Typescript, remove all the type annotations. If you are not familiar with what is and what isn't javascript, you have to start there before you can understand react.